# SSRS: Use NOT LIKE in parameter expression

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that uses 3 parameters:

- @startDate
- @endDate
- @Brand

The @startDate and @endDate parameters are working as expected.
 
@Brand is displayed as a dropdown menu with two options: B and P

When the user selects B the results returned must match the filter: `LIKE ”%.%”`
When the user selects P the results returned must match the filter: `NOT LIKE “%.%”`

I am not sure how to make this filter work for P.

Comment: so you want to achieve a multiple wildcard search?

Comment: Hi Aldrin, yes the records that correspond to 'B' consist of characters separated by one full stop. Eg. '1000045.swilde' and the records that correspond to 'P' do not have a full stop. Eg. '2056789'   So when the user select 'B' the report must return every record with a full stop in it.

Comment: Ahh I see, BI Developer already answered what will I recommend. Try his answer

Answer (score 5):

I was searching for an answer for this exact problem and I could not find. I am posting here though because I have discovered how to do it. Btw * is wildcard in SSRS

Your expression for a normal LIKE statement

```
=iif(variable LIKE "*.*", True, False)
```

Your NOT LIKE expression

```
=iif(NOT(variable LIKE "*.*"), False, True))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and least elegant) option is just to have an IF statement in your SQL:

```
IF @Brand 'B' THEN
   SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Filter LIKE '%.%'
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Filter NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Comment: Hi BIDeveloper, ill give this a try and see what i end up with.

Comment: I ended up using a CASE statement in the WHERE clause of the main query, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This below worked for me:

```
NOT(Fields!YourField.Value like "Closed Portfoy")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).